# Name, Save, and Print to pdf automatically using Document.PrintOut method (VBA Excel and Word)

Tags: vba7

I am attempting to setup a macro in Excel that allows the user to edit data that is then merged into Word using the mail merge functionality. Once the data has been merged, the macro should 1) name the file 2) print as a pdf and 3) save on the local user's desktop. I am supplying the subroutine with the following: printOutputName = name of the file to save, fileLocation = user's desktop, and selectedArea = string that has the query to select data for the merge.

Based on research, I'm using the PrintOut method to handle this but am continually receiving the popup window asking me to name and choose a location to save. Is there a reason the code is not performing these steps automatically without user input? Code is posted below, thank you in advance!

```
Sub RunMerge(printOutputName As String, fileLocation As String, selectedArea As String)
    Dim strWorkbookName As String
    Dim wdapp As New Word.Application
    Dim wddoc As Word.Document
    
    strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    
    With wdapp
        .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
        Set wddoc = .Documents.Open(fileLocation)
        With wddoc
            With .MailMerge
                .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
                .OpenDataSource name:=strWorkbookName, _
                                AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
                                Revert:=False, _
                                Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
                                SQLStatement:=selectedArea
                .SuppressBlankLines = True
                With .DataSource
                    .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
                    .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
                End With
                .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
                .Execute
                .MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument
            End With
            .Close False
        End With
        'Print the output document - would like to automate line below
        .ActiveDocument.PrintOut PrintToFile:=True, OutputFileName:=printOutputName
        .Visible = True
    End With
End Sub
```

I am adapting the code from the thread linked below for my purposes:
[Thread Link](https://www.msofficeforums.com/excel-programming/40030-mailmerge-excel-master-word-template-via-vba.html)

The merge to Word works perfectly. The query will produce the expected result I just want no user intervention after they click a button that initiates the subroutine. Based on the method [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.printout), I would expect this process to work automatically since I have set PrintToFile = True and OutputFileName = printOutputName

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I went ahead and was able to get it working with the .SaveAs2 method.